# Calculate difference between end and start time

Tags: google-sheets

How would I run the following calculation `End Time - Start Time` (so the example Hours Taken would be 0.5, 0.5 and 2) in column H from H6 to the end of the spreadsheet?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) use `=G6-F6` and google spreadsheet automatically formats the result as `hh:mm`

b) the diff is in days, so you can use `=(G6-F6)*24` to get decimal number in hours directly

Comment: I get 0.02 in the `Hours Taken` column, is it possible for it to be 0.5?

Comment: Thanks this works - how do I get it down all of column H so it updates automatically as I go on

Comment: select the cell and double click on a square in its right bottom corner

Comment: Thanks but if I enter, in F and G, can I make it so that it calculates automatically

Comment: you can pre-fill the formula on empty rows and they will display 0 if you like.. but google spreadsheets do not support `Excel Tables`-like feature as far as I know, so you would have to write a macro in javascript I guess, which I don't have experience with